# JQuery document ready - don't wait for ActiveX element

Tags: javascript, jquery, activex, document-ready

I have a page which contains ActiveX element.

When it's loaded, a dialog is opened to confirm that user allows to install it and there are fancy progressbars on the page, they are initialized on document.ready event, which is fired after ActiveX is loaded.

Is there a way not to wait form ActiveX element?

If not use document.ready event, some important scripts may happen not to be loaded yet, and this may cause error.

Are there any solutions for this case?

Please, share your advices.

Comment: Did you try putting your script at the end of the `<body>` element instead of using a `ready` handler?

Comment: Not possible - the part of page containing ActiveX & progressbars is ajax-loaded..

Comment: What do you mean by "*ajax-loaded*"? Then there is no real `document.ready` at all?

Comment: document.ready event i am talking about is fired in HTML which is loaded by AJAX.

Comment: Show us that code, please. Ajax loads usually don't fire a `ready` event, or do you use an iframe?

Comment: Application's main layout is a container. When navigating, user loads different pieces of HTML, with additional JS's etc. Yeah, paradox, document.ready IS fired in this cases again and again. Show code - I would like but it's too huge to explain and to just post it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution - loading ActiveX after document.ready event. Did not find a better one.